data attributes missing from response in jsonapidotnetcore 5.5.1
we recently upgraded the JsonAPIDotNetCore from 3.1 to 5.5.1 and also .net core from 2.2 to .NET 8.0. After upgrading the response format looks different. Earlier the complete response looks like the following.
[ data: { attributes: { Id:1, Name: "ABC" } } ]
but after upgrading the response format looks like the following.
     [
      {
       Id:1,
       Name:"ABC"
     }
    ]

So we are facing the binding issues in UI while reading the data form response. Can anyone suggest how to add the data attributes to the response?
I tried using AddMvcCore().AddDataAnnotations() in startup.cs but it is not working
Thanks
Naresh
